# Why does function work when I run lines individually but not by itself?

Tags: r, function

I have a script in which I use several functions to standardise datasets from different countries into one format.

My data looks like this:

```
machine <- ajs
database.code <- "NOR"

#1. Importing datasets - this runs without a problem
orig.data.list <- LoadTMtOriData (database.code, machine = machine, team.qc = F)

#2. Converting data into format
tmt.data.list <- Conver2TMtData (orig.data.list, database.code = database.code, machine = machine)
```

When running the `Conver2TMtData` function I get the error:

```
Error in FormatTMtCensusData(tree = tree_test, database.code = "NOR") : 
  object 'census_info' not found
```

The `Conver2TMtData` function looks like this:

```
Conver2TMtData <- function (orig.data.list, database.code, machine) {

td1 <- orig.data.list [[1]]; spp1 <- orig.data.list [[2]]; 

if (database.code == 'NOR') {
    tree <- FormatTMtTreeData (td = td1, spp = spp1, md = md1, database.code = 'NOR')
    write.csv(tree, "/Users/ajdinstarcevic/OneDrive - University of Eastern Finland/UEF/WUR/WORK/Mortality model/Data/NOR/tree.csv")
    spp <- FormatTMtSppData (tree, database.code = 'NOR')
    tree_test <- tree
    census_info <- FormatTMtCensusData (tree=tree_test, database.code = 'NOR') 
    
    
  }
```

And the `FormatTMtCensusData` function, in which I am getting the error, looks like this:

```
FormatTMtCensusData <- function (tree, database.code) {

if (database.code == 'NOR') {
   census_info <- unique (tree[,c('database.code','tmt.census.id','census.id', 'census.date','census.n','tmt.plot.id','plot.id')])
   census_info$census.contact <- 'NA'
    census_info$census.contact.email <- 'NA'
    
    
 }
```

When trying to run everything as one batch I get the error mentioned above but when I run all the lines in `FormatTMtCensusData`individually, and then go back to `Conver2TMtData`and run the function, it works.

Comment: Is the code using variables (like `md1` perhaps?) that are from the global environment? Are those variables defined when the function runs?

Comment: @JonSpring all variables are defined but I did not include them here, and that should not be a problem also, regarding your second point the `FormatTMtTreeData` function runs fine, and the object `tree`gets produced, but I get the error while running `FormatTMtCensusData` but only when running the whole batch of code, when I run individually it seems to be working.